# The text 'figure' being printed under captions in IEEEtran

Tags: floats, captions, ieeetran

Under `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}`, whenever I include a caption under a figure, right below the caption, the text 'figure' is printed. This does not happen under `\documentclass{article}`. Running the following code, I get the problem:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{figures/saturation}
\caption{Caption here.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Here's a screenshot of the problem: [image: problem]

This is the format suggested [here](http://css.paperplaza.net/conferences/support/files/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit. I am not sure I see what you mean, would you mind including a screen shot in your question?

Comment: I don't see a problem *after* using `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}`.

Comment: It's very possible that the issue depends on packages or macros you load; please add a minimal preamble that still shows the problem.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't show the problem, at least on my machine. However, the package `caption` is not recommended with `IEEEtran`.

Comment: @egreg Interesting, thanks for running it; I'll just have to run it on another machine.

Comment: Try adding `\listfiles` at the very beginning of the example code; at the end of the log file you'll find a list of the loaded packages with their version number. Add it to your question, please.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue that is not reproducible.

Comment: I don't see this issue, so I've closed. We'll need more detail (such as the log info requested) to help.